# Methods and Loops. Way over my head

Tags: c#, loops, methods, user-input

So I'm trying to get this Method of GetValidString(). Once I get this method done, the rest of the code should be easy.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ReviewEchProject
{
class Program
{
    //Arrays that can be called upon anytime
    static string[,] employeeInfo = new string[20, 3];  //Used to contain First Name, Last Name, and Title
    static int[] badgeArray = new int[20];  //Used to contain badge number


 //Main method will be used to call upon the other methods
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Employee Data Base. Please Type       a letter to accept the command.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("A = Add Employee  E = Edit Employee  S= Search     Employee  X= Exit");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        switch (userInput)
        {
            case "A":
                AddEmployee();
                break;
            case "E":
                EditEmployee();
                break;
            case "S":
                SearchEmployee();
                break;
            case "X":
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, Invalid Input. Program will now shut down.");
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Have a nice day!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }



    public static void SearchEmployee()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in the SearchEmployee method");
    }


    public static void EditEmployee()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in the EditEmployee method");
    }


    public static void AddEmployee()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < badgeArray.Length; i = i + 1)
        {
            if (badgeArray[i] != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Database is full.");
            }


            if (badgeArray[i] == 0)
            {
                int badge = GetEmployeeBadgeNumber();
                badgeArray[i] = badge;
               //Used to create badge number


               //Not sure if done correctly, but call upon three times to place names for each slot
                string firstName = GetValidString();
                employeeInfo[i, 0] = firstName;


                string lastName = GetValidString();
                employeeInfo[i, 1] = lastName;


                string titleName = GetValidString();
                employeeInfo[i, 2] = titleName;


                Console.WriteLine("Database upload ... ... Success.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static int GetEmployeeBadgeNumber()
    {
       //Needs to return an int that is at least 100 an no greater than 999. 
       //This method asks for the value from the user.  
       //Warn the user about this constraint, and stay in a loop until the user gets it right.
        return 100;
    }


    public static string GetValidString()
    {
       //loop that it stays in until the user enters a valid entry, and when the user does enter a valid entry, it should return the value the user enters 
      //ask the user to enter a value with a message that uses the passed in messageString
     //warn the user the input string must be must be at least 3 letters and less than 20. verify the length. if its not acceptable, write error message and loop again
        return "Test";
    }
}
}
```

Same conflicts apply. I'm thinking for the GetValidString() method, I should use a while loop to make sure that it can loop through everything.

**I am forced to use a 2D Array, so I have to use it.

Comment: You need to be more specific: what *exactly* are you having trouble with?  We can't just look at all this code and figure out what's wrong.  Create a [MCVE].

Comment: "I managed to get the methods to call, but I am unable to even call upon the methods" - doesn't this sentence have a small internal contradiction..?

Comment: my thought process when looking at questions like this: `if(this.QuestionIsHomeworkRelated) return;`

Comment: @Benj -- there's nothing wrong with asking homework questions, as long as the OP shows they attempted it and did some research before asking it here.  The fact that it's homework doesn't disqualify it.

Answer (score 1):

There is far too much code here to write for you. I will however offer suggestions.

1. An Employee Class with properties for fName, lName, title, badge would make this easier than using 2D arrays
2. Create an Array of Employees => `Employee[] Employees = new Employee[20]`
3. Your methods would then turn into simple loops